# How to show Ajax results in Descending order?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

Hi I have an ajax code which is able to fetch data from the sql table in ascending order.

This is the main.php

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "", "main");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM names LIMIT 8";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $id = '';  
?>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 <div class="table-responsive"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="load_data_table">  
        <?php  
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
            ?>  
                <tr>  
                 <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                </tr>  
          <?php  
          $id = $row["id"];  
          } 
          ?>  
          <tr id="remove_row">  
          td><button type="button" name="btn_more" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="btn_more" class="btn btn-success form-control">more</button></td>  
          </tr>  
          </table>  
          </div>           
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $(document).on('click', '#btn_more', function(){  
           var last_id = $(this).data("id");  
           $('#btn_more').html("Loading...");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"resources/views/frontend/ajax/one.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{last_id:last_id},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     if(data != '')  
                     {  
                          $('#remove_row').remove();  
                          $('#load_data_table').append(data);  
                     }  
                     else  
                     {  
                          $('#btn_more').html("No Data");  
                     }  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

This is the one.php

```
<?php  
$output = '';  
$id = '';  
sleep(1);  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "", "main");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE id > ".$_POST['last_id']." LIMIT 8";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
     {  
          $id = $row["id"];  
          $output .= '  
               <tbody>  
               <tr>  
                    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td> 
               </tr></tbody>';  
     }  
     $output .= '  
               <tbody><tr id="remove_row">  
                    <td><button type="button" name="btn_more" data-id="'. $id .'" id="btn_more" class="btn btn-success form-control">more</button></td>  
               </tr></tbody>  
     ';  
     echo $output;  
}  
?>
```

My sql table has two columns id and name.

This code works perfectly for ascending order i.e. if the values of "id" is increasing (1,2,3...)

I have already tried the ORDER BY clause in the SQL statement but no luck.

I would like to show the data in descending order i.e. the highest "id" value first.

Please help.

Comment: Ajax has nothing to do with ordering data in ASC or DESC manner. When you query the database you have all the rights to use ORDER BY clause to order your resultset with specific order direction ASC/DESC. AJAX is just for sending HTTP request and receiving response behind the scene ( async manner ).

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention in the initial question that I have already tried the ORDER BY Clause. Which does not works as expected. The reason is in the one.php the condition is WHERE id > Last ID. Thanks to all who warned me about the SQL injection. The code is only for local server for now and is for test purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Order By** clause. That helps sorting your results.

Modify your query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8";
```

You really should consider learning PDO as your second query may get SQL injection.

Comment: Although this answer is pointing the OP to the right direction, but the second query(in one.php) is the one which needs to be modified `$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE id > ".$_POST['last_id']." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8"; `

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention in the initial question that I have already tried the ORDER BY Clause. Which does not works as expected. The reason is in the one.php the condition is WHERE id > Last ID.